# Get number of user posts and his comments count

Tags: mongodb

in my DB collection I have the following documents structure:
`{ owner: ObjectId, counter: number }`. As a side note, this is a state I've reached to using aggregate on my real documents. So basically owner is of `ObjectId` type, and counter fields reporesents a counter.

My target is, given an input `x` of type ObjectId, to count how many times `x` presents as an owner (this would be easily achieved by using the `$count` pipe stage), but also overall sum of counters.

For example, consider the following documents and given id input `owner = 1`:

```
{ owner: 1, counter: 20 }, { owner: 2, counter: 10 }, { owner: 3, counter: 2 }, { owner: 1, counter: 5 },
```

Then, my target is to get a final aggregation result of: `{ numberOfBeingOwner: 2, overallSumCounter: 20+10+2+5 }`

How can I do it using the aggregation pipeline?

Comment: Seems like school quiz. Try this yourself to understand the concept. Here are the hints on the stages that you may want to add to your pipeline - Match and Group.

Comment: @tyrion In my country the most advanced concept in computer science is `while` loop lol. It's not school quizz -_-. Anyway, using `$match` pipe - I will lose some counters.